# How to activate Qt Quick Designer Plugin on Ubuntu based distro?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick-designer

I have Linux Mint 21, then I install qtcreator through apt repository. I want to activate
Qt Quick Designer Plugin, based on [this link](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtcreator-master/creator-qtquickdesigner-plugin.html), I should be able to activate it, but I didn't found QmlDesigner.

About Plugins Screenshot

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by trying qtcreator from [qt official](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qtcreator/7.0/7.0.2/) instead from apt. Then QmlDesigner is there.

[image: About Plugins Screenshot]

Note: You need qt account to install this.

Thank you, hope this help you too.